# what mean is “astro, turf” in “Toy Story” movie

Tags: meaning-in-context

is it mean "astro turf"?
I cannot understand why Woody said

```
                    WOODY
        Wait a minute!  No Buzz!  This way!
        There's a special ship.  I just saw
        it!

                     BUZZ
        You mean it has hyperdrive?

                     WOODY
        Hyper-active hyperdrive, and
        astro...uh, turf.
```

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. One of the expectations of Stack Exchange is that you demonstrate some initial attempts at research. For example, did you try a web search on *[astroturf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AstroTurf)*? I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 3):

I can’t recall the movie details, but from what I can tell here, it appears to be a joke.

> [AstroTurf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AstroTurf) is an American subsidiary that produces artificial turf for playing surfaces in sports.
>
> (Wikipedia)

Artificial turf is sometimes referred to as “astroturf”.

But in this context, it appears Woody is trying to assure Buzz that the ship is special by listing its special features, which include hyperdrive. But Woody doesn’t seem to know anything else about special features, so he tries to make one up.

> [astro-](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/astro-)
>   a combining form with the meaning “pertaining to stars or celestial bodies, or to activities, as spaceflight, taking place outside the earth's atmosphere,” used in the formation of compound words:
>   astronautics; astrophotography.
>   (Dictionary.com)

Woody tries to use “astro” to make up a special feature (we can tell he’s thinking by the “... uh”), as a feature with “astro” in the name could possibly describe or relate to a spaceship and appeal to Buzz. However, Woody doesn’t actually know any such feature, so he blurts out “astroturf”. This would not be a special feature on a ship, like “hyperdrive”. If there was astroturf on the ship though, I would also take it as joke (possibly ironic), as a spaceship wouldn’t need it.

Comment: that makes sense!! thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

The other answers missed the slang sense of astroturf which is ["Creating the impression of public support by paying people in the public to pretend to be supportive."](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=astroturf) So in this sense Woody would be saying the ship isn't really real, its fake.

Answer (score 0):

Many domed stadiums in the United States have artificial grass on the playing field, because there is no sunlight falling on the playing field to allow real grass. One example of this is the Houston [Astrodome](https://www.nrgpark.com/nrg-park-facilities-2/nrg-astrodome/). Because of its association with the Astrodome they call this artificial grass Astroturf.

The "turf" part of this word is [a genuine English](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/turf) word that refers to the layer of soil bound by grass.